# Calculation for number of students present,absent and overall percentage in Ireports designer

Tags: sql, postgresql, jasper-reports

I have a requirement where my report should be able to generate the total attendance of the class by selecting start date and end date.

I have created a report where till it was working fine to generate my report.But,I had got strucked in performing the calculations for total number of presence, absents and over all percentage.

My query is as shown below.

```
SELECT

 AD_COLUMN_IDENTIFIER('enroll_studentdetails1',atd.enroll_studentdetails1_id,'en_US') 
     AS Studentname,
 AD_COLUMN_IDENTIFIER('hr_employee',atd.hr_employee_id,'en_US') AS Employee, 
 AD_COLUMN_IDENTIFIER('setup_course',atd.setup_course_id,'en_US') AS cou rse,
 AD_COLUMN_IDENTIFIER('curr_class_date',atd.curr_class_date_id,'en_US') AS cla ssDateID,
 atd.curr_attnd_roster_name,atd.curr_attnd_roster_attendance,
  CASE
        WHEN atd.curr_attnd_roster_attendance = 'Present' THEN 'P'
        WHEN atd.curr_attnd_roster_attendance = 'Absent' THEN 'A'
        ELSE 'unknown'
  END AS Attendance,
 atd.curr_attnd_roster_reason,
 CAST(atd.curr_attnd_roster_classdate as DATE) as atdclassdate, 
 CAST(atd.curr_attnd_roster_starttime as DATE) as starttime,
 std.enroll_rollno,std.enroll_first_name,
 CAST(cdate.curr_classdate as DATE) as classdate,atd.setup_course_id

 from curr_attnd_roster atd,enroll_studentdetails1 std,setup_course co,curr_class_date cdate

 where std.enroll_studentdetails1_id=atd.enroll_studentdetails1_id 
 and co.setup_course_id=atd.setup_course_id
 and cdate.curr_class_date_id=atd.curr_class_date_id and $P{Course_ID}=atd.setup_course_id
```

And my preview should be displayed as shown below,

Rollno StudentName 30/05/18 01/06/18 02/06/18 03/06/18 Presents Absents    Persentage

[image: Attendees]

(NOTE:Dates are displayed by selecting classdate from my query).

I am unable to perform the calculation for present,absent and percentage which should be done.I had created the report using crosstab.

I will be very glad to you if you will be helpfull to get resolve my issue.

Comment: The select clause in the query does not match the table in the picture.  moreover,  the table in the picture seems to be result of post processing since there is no way in SQL to generate columns based on selected values (range of dates)

Comment: As u can see in the query i had converted present absent into 'P','A',To display the present and absent on the date's.  As i have returned in the note the dates are displayed by selecting the calssdate from my query.                                                                       Now what else more u need to make me confirm the query and picture are same.             I have designed the picture in jasper reports designer.